# Rails - simple form for label link not clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I've made a custom label for a 'agree with policy' checkbox. In this label I made a link which I want to set to the policy that the users will agree with. For now i've set the link to root as a test.

The checkbox is clickable. The link in the custom label however isn't?

Form:

```
 <div id="signup">
      <h2>Sign up</h2>
      <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", label: false %>
          <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "First name", label: false %>
          <%= f.input :last_name, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Last name", label: false %>
          <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length), placeholder: "Password", label: false %>
          <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, placeholder: "Confirm password", label: false %>
          <%= f.input :agree_with_policy, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline, label: ("I agree to the #{link_to 'Terms of Service', root_path}.").html_safe %>
        </div>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Below the rendered HTML:

```
<div id="signup" style="display: block;">
      <h2>Sign up</h2>
      <form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_user" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="yagrA8LqprToyfLLZkpfvJ8NALBngVshr9g4MdmqzhfQnaCFpRkfWko3YTVq9f6cyFX5ePqGXa5iAPS4aL2WsQ==">
        <div class="form-inputs">
          <div class="form-group email required user_email"><input class="form-control string email required" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email"></div>
          <div class="form-group string required user_first_name"><input class="form-control string required" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="First name" type="text" name="user[first_name]" id="user_first_name"></div>
          <div class="form-group string required user_last_name"><input class="form-control string required" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Last name" type="text" name="user[last_name]" id="user_last_name"></div>
          <div class="form-group password required user_password"><input class="form-control password required" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password"></div>
          <div class="form-group password required user_password_confirmation"><input class="form-control password required" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" id="user_password_confirmation"></div>
          <div class="form-group boolean required user_agree_with_policy"><div class="checkbox"><input name="user[agree_with_policy]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="boolean required" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[agree_with_policy]" id="user_agree_with_policy"><label class="boolean required" for="user_agree_with_policy"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> I agree to the <a href="/terms-of-service">Terms of Service</a> and the <a href="/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a>.</label></div></div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign up" class="btn" data-disable-with="Sign up">
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Pimmesz, could you show the output of HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of adding the label within `f.input` set `label: false` by setting false simple form won't be creating label for this perticular field instead we can create by own. then create a normal html `<label></label>` when it renders this will also behave same as your current view. updates will be as follows :

```
<label for="resource_agree_with_policy">I agree to the <%= link_to 'Terms of Service', root_path %></label>
<%= f.input :agree_with_policy, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline, label: false %>
```

Note: you can update HTML tags based on your styling. important thing here to know is `label: false` in `f.input :agree_with_policy`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to customize the label but I cannot click on the link? Are labels in general not clickable or could the problem be in the order of divs?

Comment: yes we can make label clickable using **jquery/javascript** events. if you still couldn't able to click on link. then i would suggest you to update your question along rendered html. it helps for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: The links dont have seperate id's or classes so clicking with JS will be challenging... added the rendered html for clarification

Comment: no for `<a>` you don't want anything to make it clickable and label won't be overriding any property as well between you html seems fine only.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most elegant solution I found:

```rb
<%= content_for(:term_label) do %>
  I agree to the <%= link_to "Terms of Service", terms_path %>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :terms, :as => :boolean, boolean_style: :inline, label: content_for(:term_label) %> 
<% end %>
```